# Where did the definition of even numbers come from?

Tags: number-theory

Is it a postulate?
I mean we all know for any integer $k$; $2k$ is even by definition.

But how can you prove it without bare intuition and definition? Who defined this in first place?

Comment: Even means that it can be divided in two equal quantities. Even is similar to the concept of fair. It is not a mathematical question, it is more an historical or cultural question.

Comment: There do exist integers evenly divisible by $2$ so it is ok to assign a name to indicate such numbers. Is your question regarding the particular English word 'even' and why that name was chosen, historically speaking?

Comment: This is more a history-question than a number-theory question.

Comment: Mathematicallly I am asking

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you expect to prove "for every integer  $k$, $2k$ is even" without the definition of "even" - you can't prove *anything* without defining all your terms first! And with the definition of "even" in hand, the proof is trivial: $k$ satisfies "$2k=2k$," and $n$ is even by definition iff there is some $i$ with $2i=n$, so $2k$ is even.

Meanwhile, note that intuition has no role at all in the proof above. The reason we think the concept of "being divisible by $2$" is important enough to deserve a special name is indeed due to intuition (or some combination of intuition and experience, depending how you define "intuition"), but once we've defined "even" that motivation is completely separate from the mathematical task of proving that $2k$ is even for every integer $k$. As usual in mathematics, we have the following sequence of events:

- Intuition/experience suggests that some concept is interesting enough to deserve its own name, "bleen".
- Having given a formal definition of "bleen" (which [may or may not match exactly the motivating intuition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis)), we now mathematically prove a fact about "bleen." Note that this result doesn't really rely on having the name "bleen" as shorthand for the concept - we could have just worked directly with the formal definition, and never used the term "bleen" at all (although this would have made the proof more cumbersome).

The second piece of this is completely independent of the first.

---

I am genuinely unclear what you are trying to ask. I suggest you think carefully about exactly what kind of "proof," and of what sort of statement, you are looking for in the first place.

Comment: So even and odd notions are postulates or they are just obvious?

Comment: Is it considered trivial for every one that what even is when you read a propf.

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone I don't understand. A *postulate*, like an *axiom* or a *theorem* or a *lemma*, is a **statement**. "Even" and "odd" are *properties." I don't know what it means to ask "is Even obvious?" anymore than I know what it means to ask "is Blue obvious?"

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone Ah, your second concept helps clear things up (I think). Yes, some words are taken to have "obvious" mathematical meanings (examples: even, odd, integer, cosine, . . .). In one sense, this is bad: everything in mathematics should be explicitly defined! But it's not like these words are lacking definitions; we are relying on the *social* fact that people know what these words mean. When we [teach computers to do math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving), we do indeed define every last thing explicitly.

Comment: Yeah I was asking that I was studyüng discrete maths and induction since morning so my mind starts to question every thing